# Unable to create an App in iTunes Connect as an App Manager

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

As I switch to a clients' profile (not logging out, logging in, but via top-right switch) in iTunes Connect and trying to add a new app as an App Manager, I get 'You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps.'. There's also a Link 'Register one here.' below. As you might have guessed, it leads to Bundle IDs page on developer.apple.com providing an opportunity to create a new Bundle ID for an app.

Let alone when I signed as an App Manager Apple Connect doesn't see the IDs I've already created as a sole developer (Why, BTW?), after clicking the link and creating a new Bundle ID, it doesn't see this new ID either.

There are [some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=You%20have%20no%20eligible%20Bundle%20IDs%20for%20iOS%20apps.) on StackOverflow, but none of the suggestions helped and none of those questions are roles related.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this one out. I was invited to iTunes Connect, but not to developer.apple.com, and that's where they update certificates.